# How to do bucket list challenge when car is pushed too far into the ocean

Tags: forza-horizon-3

How do I do a bucket list challenge when the bucket list challenge car has been pushed too far into the ocean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to reload the area so that the car is at it's default position.

First, try Fast Travelling to a Festival Site, then travelling back to the bucket list challenge (Either by land or fast travelling there). If that does not work, exit the game, load back in and go back to the bucket list site.